# Lower part of characters is clipped in the “interesting tag” textbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-watching

Jin, thank you for the great work.  I like the new design.

I found a (very) minor issue in the “interesting tag” textbox.  It is not a usability issue.  I am not sure if it is worth fixing, but anyway let me report it.

In Firefox 3.6.12 on Windows 7, the lower part of the letters in the “interesting tag” textbox is not visible.  This does not occur in IE 8 or Chrome 7 on the same system.  IE 8 seems to be using a different font in the textbox.

A screenshot (see the textbox at the last of the image):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have seen the same problem with some comments, the next line cover the lower part of the previous line.

Comment: i'm fixing this now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put in a fix, it will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Verified.  Thanks!